# Is it possible to propagate a network share mount in one docker container to others on the same host?

Tags: docker, share, mount

I'm running docker on a host and have multiple containers set up which share the same named volume (data:). So far, so good. All containers can read and write to the volume and the changes are immediately propagated. User and group are all accordingly set up as well.

However when I startup the container which is set up to mount a network share as data/subfolder it is only accessible in that one container. All other containers have an empty data/subfolder.

Now I tried different approaches like adding the :z flag, but none succeeded so far. It is key that the host is not touched, i.e. bind mounts aren't an option. It is required to be container => container, with no host interaction in-between.

Is there even any possibility to achieve this with Docker?

Comment: Maybe try using `--volumes-from` and mount all volumes in one container and then let the others --volumes-from from it?

Comment: @MattiasWadman Thanks, though I'm using v3 of compose file, where that option is unfortunately not available. I'm already doing similar with the named volume, but even sharing these wouldn't expose the content.

Comment: Ok, but mount the network share in all container inviditualy works at least? and i guess mounting the share on the host first is not an option?

Comment: @MattiasWadman I'd do that, but it's not feasible :/ The container which manages the network share does some other operations like local caching and adding that to each respective container would be bad practice and I'd have to rewrite how the network share is handled in respect to fetching the remote data. Mounting it on the host also isn't an option, I'd have gone with that but I cannot do it. I require it to be container => container sadly.

Comment: I found that bind mounts has a propagation option "shared" that is close to what you want. Unfourtunretly it seemd like "named" volumes always use propagation "rprivate". I guess you could try use a host bind mount with shared propagation and and try bind mount the same path in other containers? but no idea if it will work.